# Are there any duas that will make my particular problem go away?

Tags: practical-islam, dua

<sub>*(This is question is intentionally left vague as it is meant to provide canonical answers to a wide class of questions.)*</sub>

---

I have a very particular problem that has been bothering me. Even if I prayed for it to be removed from my life in the past, it hasn't gone away. I may have been dealing with it for such a long time that I just can't handle it anymore.

Nothing I do can make it better, but Allah has power over all things. Are there any particular duas that will solve this for me? When I search, all the duas I see are for things like protection from evil, asking for mercy, or for rewards in the hereafter, which are all good, but are there any duas that can give me actual practical results in *this* world?

Comment: Related https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75216/

Comment: @UmH I agree that there's a lot of overlap, but the linked question I feel is more general and doesn't really cover ad'iyah for particular *tangible* outcomes (hence the [tag:practical-islam] tag). I've updated the question to hopefully better differentiate what I'm asking for here.

Comment: `I have a very particular problem` This is a relative conclusion. You think it is a problem. Maybe what you are experiencing is not actually a problem. Maybe it is a favour of Allah.

Answer (score 1):

Istighfar is a very recommend whatever difficult situation you're going through.

Otherwise, I personally prefer this duaa for anxiety and sorrow. It worked with me too many times:

"O Allah, I am Your slave, son of Your slave, son of Your handmaid, my forelock is in Your hand (i.e. You have total mastery over me), Your command over me is forever executed and Your decree over me is just." I ask You by every name belonging to You which You named Yourself with, or revealed in Your Book, or You taught to any of Your creation, or You have preserved in the knowledge of the unseen with You, that You make the Qur'an the life of my heart and the light of my bosom, and a departure for my sorrow and a release for my anxiety. Note: Allah will take away the anxiety and sorrow out of the heart of him who recites this supplication, as mentioned in this hadith by our prophet (may the peace and blessings of Allah be upon him).

**Transliteration**
allaahumma innee ‛abduk-abnu-‛abdik-abnu-amatik, naaṣiyatee biyadik, maaḍin fiyya ḥukmuk, ‛adlun fiyya qaḍaa’uk, as’aluka bi kull-ismin huwa lak, sammayta bihi nafsak, aw anzaltahu fee kitaabik, aw ‛allamtahu aḥadan min khalqik, awis-ta’tharta bihi fee ‛ilmil-ghaybi ‛indak, an taj‛al-al-quraana rabee‛a qalbee, wa noora ṣadree, wa jalaa’a ḥuznee, wa dhahaaba hammee

Answer (score 1):

If you have a particular problem then it is unlikely that a specific ma'thur dua exists for your specific circumstances. Rather you may need to compose a dua in your own words and supplicate to Allah through that.

There are however ma'thur duas for practical results in this world. Below are some Quranic Duas that were made by various Prophets in difficult times and caused their problem to be solved. Using them is prescribed as it comes under following the examples of the Prophets ([Quran 6:90](https://quran.com/6/90)):

The Dua of Job (Ayub) عليه السلام . When he was sticken with illness and lost his family, he supplicated to Allah with these words and that led to it all being restored:

> وأيوب إذ نادى ربه **أني مسني الضر وأنت أرحم الراحمين** . فاستجبنا له فكشفنا ما به من ضر وآتيناه أهله ومثلهم معهم رحمة من عندنا وذكرى للعابدين
>
> And [mention] Job, when he called to his Lord, "**Indeed, adversity has touched me, and you are the Most Merciful of the merciful.**"
>
> So We responded to him and removed what afflicted him of adversity. And We gave him [back] his family and the like thereof with them as mercy from Us and a reminder for the worshippers [of Allah].
>
> <sup>— [Quran 21:83-84](https://quran.com/21/83-84?translations=20)</sup>

The dua of Jonah عليه السلام . He was thrown overboard from a ship and swallowed by a fish. He supplicated with the following wording which lead to him being safely rescued.

> وذا النون إذ ذهب مغاضبا فظن أن لن نقدر عليه فنادى في الظلمات **أن لا إله إلا أنت سبحانك إني كنت من الظالمين** . فاستجبنا له ونجيناه من الغم وكذلك ننجي المؤمنين
>
> And [mention] the man of the fish (Jonah), when he went off in anger and thought that We would not decree [anything] upon him. And he called out within the darknesses, "**There is no deity except You; exalted are You. Indeed, I have been of the wrongdoers.**"
>
> So We responded to him and saved him from the distress. And thus do We save the believers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 21:87-88](https://quran.com/21/87-88?translations=20)</sup>

The Duas of Noah عليه السلام . He supplicated with it when he was overcome by the disbelievers, and this lead to the flood and saving of Noah and his family from it.

> فدعا ربه **أني مغلوب فانتصر**
>
> So he invoked his Lord, "**Indeed, I am overpowered, so help**."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 54:10](https://quran.com/54/10?translations=20)</sup>

The Dua of Moses عليه السلام  when the Egyptians planned to assassinate him. The result of which was that he was saved from them:

> فخرج منها خائفا يترقب قال **رب نجني من القوم الظالمين**
>
> So he left it, fearful and anticipating [apprehension]. He said, "**My Lord, save me from the wrongdoing people.**"
>
> <sup>— [Quran 28:21](https://quran.com/28/21?translations=20)</sup>

The Dua of Moses عليه السلام . He supplicated with these words when he arrived in Madyan homeless and destitute. This lead to him being granted accommodation, employment and a spouse:

> فسقى لهما ثم تولى إلى الظل فقال **رب إني لما أنزلت إلي من خير فقير**
>
> So he watered [their flocks] for them; then he went back to the shade and said, "**My Lord, indeed I am, for whatever good You would send down to me, in need.**"
>
> <sup>— [Quran 28:24](https://quran.com/28/24?translations=20)</sup>

All of these duas have generic wordings and can be adapted for any problem. There are also many duas which are recorded in ahadith for relief from distress, adversity, grief etc. Some of them are covered [here on islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/309/duaas-prayers-at-times-of-distress) and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75216/).

You can also increase the chance of your dua being accepted as follows:

- Make dua during times of acceptance such as on the day of Arafat, in Ramadan, on Friday, at the time of dawn, at the time of iftar, after daily prayers, during rain, in prostration etc.
- Have conviction that Allah will respond to it.
- Ask forgiveness for your sins.
- Make sure your income etc. is halal.
- Use a wasilah, such as through the names of Allah, or through good deeds etc.
- Before and after the Dua praise and glorify Allah and send blessings on the Prophet.

Finally, if the problem is not being removed even after your duas, then you should show patience and continue making dua. A dua is only a supplication to Allah, it is Allah's choice when, how and whether he accepts it.

> #### فيكشف ما تدعون إليه إن شاء
>
> He would remove that for which you invoked Him if He willed
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:41](https://quran.com/6/41?translations=20)</sup>