# I need allah's help

Tags: depression

I moved to a different country and I dont know their language I am learning it but they have English at school that's kind of the only class which I'm getting full marks/ good grades in
I feel so depressed I miss my old home and my family and friends and my old school I hate life because of all of this I lost hope and nothing makes me happy I try to study but I break down everytime how can I ask allah for help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to say or do during times of distress, difficulty or calamity?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75216/what-to-say-or-do-during-times-of-distress-difficulty-or-calamity) also see [Are there any duas that will make my particular problem go away?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75339/are-there-any-duas-that-will-make-my-particular-problem-go-away)

Comment: From the words of your question i guess that English is not the native language of the country where you are staying? Try to make contact to the people, but don't force it. Start with learning standard greetings and responses. It will make it easier to the locals to think of you as "the new one" instead of "the alien one that doesn't even return a greeting". It will it make easier to make contacts, and this will very probably not only help you to a better mood.