# Is there a Du'a to remove pain by placing your hand or finger on the particular spot?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, islamic-scholar

Which Ahadith and references from the scholars could be provided to answer this question?

<sup>- I will post an answer to this question</sup>

<sup>- Square brackets [ ] are additions or/and individual changes (for clarity) of the author's thread</sup>

---

<sup>Special thread related to "[What to say or do during times of distress, difficulty or calamity?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75216/what-to-say-or-do-during-times-of-distress-difficulty-or-calamity/75217#75217)"</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are narrations about putting ones hand on the particular place where you feel the pain (so that Allah removes it, inshallah):

> Narrated by A'isha: The Prophet ﷺ used to treat some of his wives by passing his right hand over the place of ailment and used to say: "*O Allah, the Lord of the people! Remove the trouble and heal the patient, for You are the Healer. No healing is of any avail but Yours; healing that will leave behind no ailment*" (Allahumma rabban-nas, adh-hibil-bas, ishfih wa antash-shafi, la shifa'a illa shifa'uk(a), shifa'an la yughadiru saqaman)
>
> <sup>Al-Bukhari ([5743](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5743))</sup>
>
> <sup>Ibn as-Sunni ([551](https://shamela.ws/book/13132/1056)), graded Sahih by Shaykh Hilal in his Tahqiq ([2/626](https://shamela.ws/book/123672/623#p1)), slightly different: (Bismillah, adh-hibil-ba's, Rabban-Nas, wa-shfi antash-shafi, la shifa'a illa shifa'uk(a), shifa'an la yughadiru saqaman)</sup>

---

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: "*Place your hand at the place where you feel pain in your body and say: 'In the name of Allah'* (Bismillah) *three times, and seven times 'I seek refuge with Allah and with His Power from the evil that I find and that I fear'* (A'udhu bil-lahi wa qudratihi min sharri ma a-jidu wa u-hadhir)
>
> <sup>Muslim ([2022](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2202))</sup>
>
> "*Put your right hand on it and say: In the Name of Allah, I seek refuge in the might and power of Allah from the evil of what I feel and what I fear* (Bismillah, a'udhu bi-i'z-zatil-lahi wa qudratihi min sharri ma a-jidu wa u-hadhir) *7 times.*" U'thman bin abi al-A's ath-Thaqafi said: 'I said that, and Allah healed me.'
>
> <sup>Ibn Majah ([3522](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3522))</sup>
>
> "*Rub* (or wipe) [the place] *with your right hand 7 times and say: I seek refuge in Allah's might, power, and authority, from the evil of what I find* (A'udhu bi-i'z-zatil-lahi wa qudratihi wa Sultanihi min sharri ma a-jid)
>
> <sup>At-Tirmidhi ([2080](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2080)) which Abu I'sa classed Hasan Sahih</sup>
>
> "[Firstly, say once:] *In the Name of Allah, I seek refuge in Allah's might and power from the evil of this pain I feel*" (Bismillah, a'udhu bi-i'z-zatil-lahi wa qudratihi min sharri ma a-jidu min waja'i hadha), *then lift your hand and repeat that an odd number of times.*"
>
> <sup>Al-Mustadrak ([4/244](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/8358)), which Al-Hakim classed Sahih and Imam Dhahabi agreed upon</sup>

There are also various narrations which speak about using your (index) finger:

> Sufyan narrated to us from A'bd Rabih ibn Sa'id, from A'mrah, from A'isha, that the Messenger of Allah ﷺ used to, when a person complained of something or had a wound or injury, he would say with his finger like this, and Sufyan put his index finger on the ground, then lifted it, saying: "*In the name of Allah, the soil of our land, the saliva of some of us, to cure our sick, by the permission of our Lord*" (Bismillah, turbatu ardina, bariqati ba'dina, li-yushfa bihi saqimuna, bi-idhni Rabbina)
>
> <sup>Muslim ([2194](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2194))</sup>